# How do I omit similar content in a for loop based on the first letter in title?

Tags: forloop

I've got a for loop that is returning the first letter of the entry title. I have a number of entries so I almost get a complete alphabet except that there are too many of many letters. I only want one 'a', one 'b', one 'c' and so 
forth. And no letter if there is no entry to correspond to it.

```
{% for alpha in craft.entries.section('advertisers').order('title asc') %}
    <a href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ alpha.title|first }}">{{ alpha.title|first }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This code returns:
A A A B B B B B C C E E E E G G H H K M M M M P P R R S S S T T U U U W W
but I want it to return A B C E G H K M P R S T U W

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the only code relevant to your question is the first for loop, right?

Comment: yup. I removed some code to clean it up. I'm still learning the ways of Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only unique letters, you can build a new array and only merge first letters that are not already in the array like this:

```
{% set letterArray = [] %}

{% for alpha in craft.entries.section('advertisers').order('title asc') %}
  {% if alpha.title|first not in letterArray %}
    {% set letterArray = letterArray|merge([alpha.title|first]) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for letter in letterArray %}
  <a href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ letter }}">{{ letter }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Completely untested, but something like this should work:

```
{% set letterArray = [] %}

{% for alpha in craft.entries.section('advertisers').order('title asc') %}
    {% set letterArray = letterArray|merge([alpha.title|first]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for letter in letterArray %}
    <a href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ letter }}">{{ letter }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "string" as second argument."

Comment: I did say it wasn't tested... try the updated answer.

Comment: No error but still returns the same as my original code. The suggestion by Alex worked perfect. I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Foiled by @AlexRoper yet again!